# Mysql storing urls (not http)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, ftp

I have read in SO advice on storing URLs in MySQL to use `TEXT` or `VARCHAR(2083)`.
Do these kind of approaches apply to ftp urls as well? Or is the ftp such that we can improve (in regards to length) on the datatype to use?

Answer (score 0):

You are storing URLs as strings in your tables, http or ftp doesn't matter.

Go ahead with you `TEXT` or `VARCHAR(2083)`.